# Struts 2 - Java - Variable casting error (Trying to prevent XSS)

Tags: java, variables, struts2, xss

I really am not sure how to ask this question but if it is not suitable for SO I am sorry.

- I have a getter method that accepts only an Integer.
- In my web form I have a hidden field that can be manipulated using firebug
- When the user hacks in a string it appears to be sent to the server
- I get various 'Error setting expression' errors in eclipse (obviously as it is trying to cast a string to an int)
- I check back in firebug and the value is still set to the string
- I check in the response and the string has definitely been sent to the server and then sent back by the server
- This is obviously a problem as someone could whack some script in it for some XSS
- THIS is easily fixed by adding and if invoked on a value range in the setter else sets to 0.

My real question is... why if the compiler doesnt like the string casting to an int, does the server still allow it to be returned?
I was expecting a big barf and for it to tell me NO!
My fix at the moment is purely a hack as I do not understand it enough. To me, it feels like after the getter barfs, it goes somewhere else?

Is this a Struts2 thing?

Comment: Do you have an example code?

Comment: If your bean property is typed as Integer then it won't be written. I can't see where is the problem. Why the returned string can make easy XSS?

Comment: well for example, if I were to make the value 1234020636});$('document').ready(function(){alert('XSS');
Then it would run the alert. This is not a problem, I have sorted this

Comment: My problem is, why is the string being sent in the response from the server when it should be barfing on the fact that it is not an int

Comment: What is sending back a string when it realises it is not an integer

Comment: As you may tell, I have not been working with Struts2 for very long... infact web apps at all

Comment: I understand that the server returns the string and I agree that is not a good thing but I can't see how that may help attackers.

Comment: I can't figure out why the server returns other thing that a 500 error response. Any tunning?

Comment: Why do you think it's sending back, if you don't want it sending back why didn't you do it?

Comment: @RomanC Not my code that is why! I just need to know why it is sending it back, and where, I am thoroughly confused

Comment: @user270349 I know right. A 500 would be great, at least then I would know that the server gets it and say NOOO... instead the server gets it and goes "ah go'on then"!

Comment: @user270349 I was wondering if by any chance it was a struts thing, to see a value is not being cast, and then to force it in.

Comment: @Phish I'm precisely understand that you don't know how to do it, what to do, don't you. I have suggested to you to write a code instead of express your ideas without evidence to support them.